# Lost intellisense and squiggles

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason, all my new projects created using dotnet no longer have intellisense or squiggles.  However, if I open an old project, those still have intellisense and squiggles.

How do I get intellisense and squiggles in my new projects?

Using C# in VSC on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04).

---

**VERSIONS**

Visual Studio Code 1.60.0
C# for Cisual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) 1.23.15

dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.400 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

---

**COMMAND USED**

dotnet new console -o project_name

Comment: What extensions have you installed that should provide the code linting? And are you sure that you are trusting the workspace of the new projects because when opening the project in restricted mode, not all features work as expected.

Comment: it's unclear whether you use [dev containers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/dotnet), but I'm wondering if you can dive it a go?

Comment: @prd The only extension I have installed is [Visual Studio Code 1.60.0 C# for Cisual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) 1.23.15].  I don't get prompted to trust the workspace.  I'll look into that now as I am not sure how or of I have ever done that in the past for the projects which do have code linting.